# Passing Variables from Partial View MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a page with a table that is populated (using jQuery) from a database.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to search the table (or I guess the correct word is "filter").
I have a "partial view" .cshtml file that creates a search bar inside the file where the table is.  My question is how can I pass a variable (which will be the only thing inside a text box when the search button is pressed) from the partial view file to the "actual" view file so I can use it as the parameter for the filter?
I've done lots of searching about this online and can't find exactly what I'm looking for.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Check out this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ . You can call your controller and get your partial view. You can pass your filter variables with it too, to get the correct response.

Comment: @mattfetz okay, so if I have the file "StudentAllotment.cshtml", and the partial view is in file "_StudentSearchBar.cshtml", and I'm getting the variable "filtering" from the StudentSearchBar file (which holds the desired filtering parameters), I would call:
$.get("~/Views/StudentAllotments/Allotments.cshtml", {filtering});
From the StudentSearchBar file after I populate "filtering", but how would I then use the variable in the other file?
Thanks!

Comment: I gave a example of what you should do to get a partial in MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("~/Student/GetStudent?id=1", function(html){
        //append html
    })
})
```

**C#**

Lets say this get method is in a controller called Student

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetStudent(int id)
{
    //use the paremeter in this case id to create a model with the correct data

    //_StudentPartial being the partial html and model being the model that populates the partial
    return PartialView("_StudentPartial",model);
}
```

Comment: `$.get('@Url.Action("GetStudent", "Student"), { id: 1 }, function(html) { ...`!!

Comment: @StephenMuecke thats the way I do it too, but for learning purposes I wrote out the entire url with parems in it for easier understanding.

Comment: Especially for _learning purposes_ you should showing OP  the right way :)

Comment: @mattfetz I'm not sure if this is exactly what I'm looking for.  I want to be able to pass the variable from the partial view to the main view when a button in the partial view is pressed.  Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: @JosiahNusbaum Well you can have a jquery click listener on the button, get the value from the partial and append the value in a hidden input somewhere else in the html where you want it. But partial view is just a html page that you are inserting to another html. Once you add the partial to the page it essential is part of the main page.

Comment: @mattfetz okay, that's the information I was looking for! So I could pretty much declare a variable that is populated when the button is clicked, and then filter with the same variable, without redeclaring it or anything?

Comment: Yea basically when you get your value you want to store find the hidden input `<input type=hidden id="someId" />` and do some jquery like this `$("#someId").val(yourValue)`.

Comment: Here is info on the jquery click as well if you are not familiar with it. http://api.jquery.com/click/